# Как подменить значение в цикле на другое с таймером?

Tags: python

У нас есть бесконечный цикл, он выводит переменную со **значением_1** в консоль, нужно подменить это значение на некоторое время **значением_2** и оно будет выводится в консоль в течение этого времени, а когда время выйдет, в консоль снова будет выводится **значение_1**.

Comment: Цикл в цикле сделать

Answer (score 0):

Выводит в бесконечном цикле **This value** всегда, кроме как между 5 и 10 секундой -- в этом случае выводится **Another value**:

```
import time

value = ''
while True:
    current_time = time.perf_counter()
    #print(current_time)
    if current_time > 5 and current_time < 10:
        value = 'Another value'
    else:
        value = 'This value'
    print(value)
```

Comment: А если надо чтобы все было на одной строке, нужно сделать `print(value, end="\r")` ( примечание для автора)